# Последовательность выполнения функций

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Часть 1. Пишу слайдер на JQuery. Решил сделать так чтобы текстовый контент выводился по порядку (например, там контент из 3-x div), нужно было выводить с анимацией каждый (появился полностью один, начал появляться другой и т.д.). Но все появляется одновременно.
Код

```
contentSlide: {
  setup: function () {
    content = slider.find('ul li').eq(slideIndex).find('div').eq(0);
    content.count = content.find('div').length;
    content.find('div').hide();
    action.contentSlide.start();
  },
  start: function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var a, b, c, d;
      a = content.find('div').eq(i);
      b = a.attr('data-item-animate');
      action.contentSlide.Item(b, a, i);
    }
  },
  Item: function (a, b, c) {
    b.show().addClass(a + ' animated');
  }
}
```

Это отрывок кода. В Item обрабатываются анимации и вывод. 
Сначала скрываю все div и потом хочу по одному выводить. В start циклом беру каждый div и по указанному у него атрибуту выполняю анимацию. Для анимации использую animate.css

Часть 2. Использование .promise помогло, но частично.

```
start: function () {
  if (content.index < content.count) {
    var a, b;
    a = content.find('div').eq(content.index);
    b = a.attr('data-item-animate');
    action.contentSlide.Item(b,a);
  }
},
Item: function (a, b) {
  b.fadeIn(1500);
  b.promise().done(function () {
    content.index++;
    action.contentSlide.start();
  });
}
```

Эта конструкция работает так как надо, но если поменять b.fadeIn(1500) на b.show().addClass(a + 'animated') то все снова плачевно.

Есть ли решение? Или делать всю анимацию на js?

Comment: Если нужно могу выложить в гитхабе весь код. Там уже есть но без реализации вывода контента: https://github.com/zurrdev/ZurrSlider

Comment: Поробовал $.when(...).done(...) не помогло.

Comment: посмотри в сторону [`.promise`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Answer (score 0):

Решил все, но конечно же знаю, что у меня очень плохой велосипед получился...

```
Item: function (a, b) {
  b.fadeIn(300).addClass(a + ' animated').delay(1500);
  b.promise().done(function () {
    content.index++;
    action.contentSlide.start();
  });
}
```